# How to import an Eclipse C++ project into Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to import my Eclipse C++ projects into Visual Studio 2019, but Visual Studio seems not be able to recognize my projects in Eclipse. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks a lot!